# getting error with pthread mutex attributes

Tags: multithreading

I am getting problem when I am giving pthread_mutex_attr as a parameter while creating thread. If I pass attribute as **NULL** it is working fine, but not desired this NULL,

Here I  am posting code, Please help me correct my mistakes and learn things.

```c
pthread_mutex_t thread_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_t thread1;

pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
pthread_mutex_init(&thread_mutex, &attr);

ret = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, my_func, (void *)message);
pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);

pthread_mutex_destroy(&thread_mutex);
pthread_exit(NULL);
```

if I pass attr like this

ret = pthread_create(&thread1,&attr,upload_data,(void *)message);

This is giving segmentation fault.

Comment: @Ulrich... Thanks I was trying to exactly like that, but didnt`t get that formatting. I have to learn a lot about everything. :)

Comment: In addition to the already accepted answer, note that you are creating a thread, which may reference a specific mutex (otherwise, why is that mutex even there?), and then, before the thread has finished (i.e. you haven't called `pthread_join()` on it yet), you destroy that mutex and exit. Even if it's not causing you issues now, it's likely to bite you in the future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of error you get as you never specified what exactly your problem is but I assume you can't compile your code.

From `man pthread_create`:

```
   #include <pthread.h>

   int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

This shows that pthread_create doesn't use `pthread_mutex_attr` but `pthread_attr`

Comment: At the place where we need to provide attributes, if I pass NULL thread is created. But I want that thread with mutex with no default attribute,but specified one.

Comment: this is the link from where I am trying to learn about Posix Thread.

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes

Comment: @Krishna as i said your attr has the wrong type. `pthread_mutex_attr` != `pthread_attr`. The first attr is used to determine thread specific settings (stack size, etc.) If you want to pass the mutex to your function you have to pass it in `arg` and not `attr`.